# Compare two frames by parts R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I want to compare two data frames by parts. Here is an example of my data frames:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,6,3,4), b=letters[1:4])
```

I would like to write a function which  finds the two sequential rows in a1 which also exists in data frame a2  ( both columns have to match) and save it in new frame.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dual.matches <- match(a1$a, a2$a) == match(a1$b, a2$b) 
sequential.dual.matches <- with(rle(dual.matches), rep(replace(values, lengths==1, FALSE), lengths))

a1[sequential.dual.matches, ]
#   a b
# 3 3 c
# 4 4 d
```